# How do I use (install?) jQuery autocomplete plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

My understanding is that to use the plugin I need to [insert this code into the header](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Autocomplete):

```
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/demo/main.css" type="text/css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.css" type="text/css" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/lib/jquery.bgiframe.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/lib/jquery.dimensions.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jquery.com/view/trunk/plugins/autocomplete/jquery.autocomplete.js"></script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    var data = "Core Selectors Attributes Traversing Manipulation CSS Events Effects Ajax Utilities".split(" ");
$("#example").autocomplete(data);
  });
  </script>
```

I did that and then I put the form in the html:

```
self.response.out.write("""
API Reference: <input id="example" /> (try "C" or "E")         """)
```

but nothing is happenning. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using the newer [jQueryUI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) via the [Google CDN](http://code.google.com/apis/libraries/).

To include it in your application, use something like this

```
<!-- in your <head> section -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
```

The `smoothness` string in the URL refers to the jQueryUI theme. You can change this to whatever you want. See http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/#themeGallery

```
<!-- just before the closing </body> tag -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(function($) {
        var data = [
            "Core",
            "Selectors",
            "Attributes",
            "Traversing",
            "Manipulation",
            "CSS",
            "Events",
            "Effects",
            "Ajax",
            "Utilities"
        ];
        $("#example").autocomplete({
            source: data
        });
    });
</script>
```

The `1` references in these URLs refer to the version number. Just using `1` means use the latest version from the 1 branch